# GitHub for Windows Tool. Get the new changes without pushing new changes

Tags: git, github-for-windows

I am using Github tool for windows. I want to get the latest changes from the team repository without pushing my changes to the repository. Is there any option for this in GitHub for Windows tool?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way to do this is by making your changes on a local branch. As long as you don't publish the branch, GitHub for Windows will not push it to the remote repository. Then, when you want to pull you can get the changes into your local working branch by doing the following:

1. Switch to the branch on which the remote changes are
2. Click on sync
3. Switch back to the local branch on which you were working
4. Merge the changes from the synced branch into your own branch

Finally, when you want to push your changes, you can either publish your local branch or you can go to the synced branch and merge your own branch into that, followed by another synchronization.

Alternatively, you can use the Git Shell to pull without pushing. You can find the Git Shell in the start menu in the folder `GitHub, Inc` (Windows 7), or you can type `Git Shell` in the start screen (Windows 8). After starting the Git Shell you have to navigate into the project folder, using the `cd`-command. After that you can execute the command `git pull`.